# Create Form and WebBrowser at runtime

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, twebbrowser

I'm using Delphi 7 and trying to create a `WebBrowser` inside a `Form`, both at run time, but can't make it work. Here is the code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Form: TForm;
  Brws: TWebBrowser;
begin
  Form := TForm.Create(nil);
  try
    Form.Width := 500;
    Form.Height := 500;
    Form.BorderStyle := bsDialog;
    Form.Position := poScreenCenter;
    Form.Caption := 'Select the Option';
    Brws := TWebBrowser.Create(Form);
    Brws.ParentWindow := Form.Handle;
    TWinControl(Brws).Parent := Form;
    Brws.Align := alClient;
    Brws.AddressBar := False;
    Brws.MenuBar := False;
    Brws.StatusBar := False;
    Application.ProcessMessages;
    if Form.ShowModal = mrOk then
      Brws.Navigate('https://www.google.com');
  finally
    Form.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The result is like WebBrowser is not responding. I got a white screen and no error messages.

[image]

Please, what am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: The form is displayed with `Form.ShowModal` and waits until it's closed to continue in your code so you never navigate anywhere while the form is visible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are displaying the Form using its `ShowModal()` method, which is a synchronous (aka blocking) function that does not exit until the Form is closed.  So, you are never reaching the call to `Navigate()` while the Form is open.

You have two options:

- Use `Show()` instead of `ShowModal()`.  `Show()` signals the Form to display itself, and then exits immediately, allowing subsequent code to run while the Form is open.  As such, you will have to get rid of the `try...finally` and instead use the Form's `OnClose` event to free the Form when it is closed, eg:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Form: TForm;
  Brws: TWebBrowser;
begin
  Form := TForm.Create(Self);
  Form.Width := 500;
  Form.Height := 500;
  Form.BorderStyle := bsDialog;
  Form.Position := poScreenCenter;
  Form.Caption := 'Select the Option';
  Form.OnClose := BrowserFormClosed;

  Brws := TWebBrowser.Create(Form);
  TWinControl(Brws).Parent := Form;
  Brws.Align := alClient;
  Brws.AddressBar := False;
  Brws.MenuBar := False;
  Brws.StatusBar := False;

  Form.Show;
  Brws.Navigate('https://www.google.com');
end;

procedure TForm1.BrowserFormClosed(Sender: TObject;
  var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caFree;
end;
```

- Otherwise, if you want to keep using `ShowModal()` then move the call to `Navigate()` into the Form's `OnShow` or `OnActivate` event instead, eg:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Form: TForm;
  Brws: TWebBrowser;
begin
  Form := TForm.Create(nil);
  try
    Form.Width := 500;
    Form.Height := 500;
    Form.BorderStyle := bsDialog;
    Form.Position := poScreenCenter;
    Form.Caption := 'Select the Option';
    Form.OnShow := BrowserFormShown;

    Brws := TWebBrowser.Create(Form);
    TWinControl(Brws).Parent := Form;
    Brws.Align := alClient;
    Brws.AddressBar := False;
    Brws.MenuBar := False;
    Brws.StatusBar := False;

    Form.ShowModal;
  finally
    Form.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.BrowserFormShown(Sender: TObject);
var
  Form: TForm;
  Brws: TWebBrowser;
begin
  Form := TForm(Sender);
  Brws := TWebBrowser(Form.Components[0]);
  Brws.Navigate('https://www.google.com');
end;
```